# Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/29-07-2017_06:39:14_10AU61_1.csv) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in

Tags: php

I am trying to copy files from source to destination.But it's giving an error on this line:

```
  if($imageFileType == "csv" && move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], $target_file))
```

Comment: Please, post your code in able to clearly answering you

Answer (score 0):

First check the directory exist or not. If its not created then use

```
mkdir()
```

and create it. After creating use your function to save file.